# How to cut segmentx of X words around sepcific word - out of text corpora

Tags: r, text-analysis

I am analyzing speeches that I uploaded to R. My dataframe includes a row to each speech with metadata and the entire text of the speech.

BUT - I don't want to only analyze the speech in whole but also to find a way to analyze chunks of texts around a specific word. For example - 50 words before and after reference to "RED"... 
Is there anyway to create a new dataframe - that each row will be the segmented text AND I will manage also to keep the metadata (it is not the same table since there are more reference to "red" than speeches - so in one speech there can be 4 segments around "red" and some will not have any reference at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `quanteda` package implements a keyword-in-context function that does exactly this. If the dataframe containing your speeches is `df`, and the column containing the text is `texts`, then this should work:

```
library(quanteda)
kw <- kwic(df$texts, "red", 50)
```

The third argument specifies the size of the context window. `kw` is now a dataframe with columns for the target word and its preceding and following contexts.

Comment: THANK you very much